# Django REST Framework File Uploads not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

In Django REST Framework file uploads,

I have one Model which has couple of fields along with a FileField which is an attachment which is optional.

```
class Task(model.Model):
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=default_location, null=True, blank=True)
    ... some extra fields
```

There is a ModelViewset for this model to implement CRUD functionality. 
User can create an entry in the model with/without an attachment.

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.all()
```

Serilaizer has an extra BooleanField to decide whether to keep the last attachment or not. This field would be rendered as a checkbox in the front end.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    keep_previous_attachment = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta: 
        model = Task
        fields = ['id','attachment', 'heading']
```

When user creates the new entry, it works as expected. it stores the attachment to its default location.
When user updates the entry with/without attachment, things dont work as expected.

When I use PUT method to the update URL of the ModelViewset, 
1. When the django server is restarted, first attempt works fine. Previous attachment is overwritten. 
2. All the subsequent requests to the URL does not work. It just renames the older file and the renamed file becomes current attachment.
3. If I use PATCH method, i cant access keep_previous_attachment in the validated_data of the serializer class at all.
4. Everything is working as expected before the instance.save is called. That method is somehow referencing the old attachment, renaming to something else and storing the renamed attachment as the current attachment and the old attachment still lives in the uploads folder.

Expected outcome is: 
When the user updates the existing entry using the update views, 
previous attachment should get overwritten i.e. delete the previous file and store the new one.

I have overwritten the update method on the serializer class whose code is given below. I have copy pasted the original update code of the serializer class and made some changes. I am unable to achieve the expected outcome as instance.save method is not overwriting the previous attachment i.e. it is still storing the previous attachment even when new attachment is being processed till the point instance.save method is called. I tried with passing, force_update=True, it is also not working. I cant wrap my head around whats wrong here.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):

    from rest_framework.serializers import raise_errors_on_nested_writes
    raise_errors_on_nested_writes('update', self, validated_data)

    from rest_framework.utils import model_meta
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(instance)

    keep_old = validated_data.pop("keep_previous_attachment")
    validated_attachment = validated_data.pop("attachment")

    # Simply set each attribute on the instance, and then save it.
    # Note that unlike `.create()` we don't need to treat many-to-many
    # relationships as being a special case. During updates we already
    # have an instance pk for the relationships to be associated with.

    for attr, value in validated_data.items():
        if attr in info.relations and info.relations[attr].to_many:
            field = getattr(instance, attr)
            field.set(value)
        else:
            setattr(instance, attr, value)

    if keep_old is False:

        # delete the references to the older attachment
        instance.attachment = None 
        instance.save()


        deletion_path = os.path.join("location_of_folder")

        deleted = delete_task_attachments(deletion_path, request)

        instance.attachment = validated_attachment

    # if keep_old is True:
    #     instance.attachment is untouched by the code, so no update will happen.

    # print()
    # print("BEFORE SAVE")
    # print("instance.attachment")
    # print(instance.attachment)
    # print()

    instance.save()

    # print()
    # print("After SAVE")
    # print("instance.attachment")
    # print(instance.attachment)
    # print()

    return instance
```

Please guide me to a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know for sure that the code inside `if keep_old is False:` is running?

Comment: YES, I tested it several times in the past three days. For the purpose of showing you the code, I have removed several print statements which show me a details log of which piece of code has run. I am sure that the instance.save() is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: everything is working as expected before the instance.save is called. That method is somehow referencing the old attachment, renaming to something else and storing the renamed attachment as the current attachment and the old attachment still lives in the uploads folder.